# What machine learning algorithm should I use?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, regression

I'm trying to write an algorithm to estimate the mass of objects that I know the system of.

My data is of the form of x and y points, so I could either represent these as multiple x and y points, or as a distribution by representing the average and deviation of the x and y points. This would likely depend on the parameters of the algorithm.

I don't need a classifier, I'm looking for a number value estimation.

e.g., x values: {1,2,3,...}, y values: {1,2,3,...} -> mass: 5, 
or x values:{2 (mean), 1 (std)} y: {2,1} -> 5

I'm pretty new to machine learning, and a classifier doesn't seem like the way to approach this, and regression learning algorithms I've looked up seem to try to estimate parameters, not results.

I'm also planning on doing this in Python, but I don't need a package or something, a general algorithm should put me on the right track.

### Edit in response to blubb

My data is given in the form of a set of x points, a set of y points, and a mass.
e.g.,

```
x values   |   y values   | mass
--------------------------------
1 2 3 4    |   1 2 3 4    | 6.7
2 3 4 5    |   2 3 4 5    | 7.9
```

And I would receive an input, like:

```
x values   |   y values
-----------------------
5 6 7      |   8 9 10
```

Another way of resenting it (which may be smarting in terms of a vector space) would be to represent the values by their means and std, so my training data would become:

```
x mean | x std | y mean | y std | mass
--------------------------------------
2.5    | 1     | 2.5    | 1     | 6.7
3.5    | 1     | 3.5    | 1     | 7.9
```

These are obviously not the real values, but representative examples. (All values are floats)

Comment: What do you mean by "mass"?  You'll either need some way of computing that from the data (in which it probably isn't machine learning), or you'll need some training data that provides the mass for given inputs.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, does it? It's just some number that I'm trying to have an algorithm predict. I have data that is xvalues, yvalues -> mass number.

I'm assuming that the x and y points / spread have an effect on the mass.

It's not algorithmic (like density*volume = mass), it's predictive and I do have training data for it.

Comment: Well, but it's hard to give a general algorithm for "how do I estimate something".  Typically in a machine-learning context you would have a set of individual "cases", with an individual "case" containing various input variables and one or more output variables.  Given that, your second form using mean and stdev seems more reasonable, since it associates one set of scalar values with one scalar value.  Have you looked at [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/)?  It has various algorithms.  Which of them is "best" is often found by just trying several to see which one gives best performance.

Comment: I was looking at that earlier. I suppose I was moreso confused about what algorithms I could use, because classifiers return, well, classes (not values) and regression seems to parse parameters, not results. But if you're saying it can also do results, I'll definitely give it a more in depth look. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and is probably better suited for [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Xyxyl: Regression estimates parameters, but you can then use those estimated parameters to predict the results on new data.

Comment: @Xyxyl: Your description is too broad to answer the question reasonably. However, I tried to give a general description of regression methods. Hopefully, this helps you in understanding what kind of description is needed.

Comment: @blubb, you're right, I need to look more into the collection process and the different algorithms available. It's obviously now that I want some form of a regression, which is more than I knew when I asked. Thanks for the help, and I'll do some exploring on my own to get a better feel for the fits and what information I need to collection / figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking to estimate a function `f: R² -> R`, therefore regression is the family of methods you should be looking into. Which kind of regression however depends largely on the relation between `(x, y)` and `mass`.

Generally described, a regression method defines a cost function `c: R² x F -> R+` and a set `F` of functions to choose from. Often the set `F` is infinite and parametrized in some form. This leaves most regression methods with the problem of estimating the parameters that determine the optimal `f` (what you referred to as 'estimating parameters').

In order to determine which regression method is most suitable, you'll have to find out the following things:

- what is a meaningful cost function `c`?
- how to choose the set `F` of functions?

For example, linear regression chooses the linear least squares cost function and sets the defines `F` to be the set of all linear functions `f: R² x R`. This may or may not be what you want, depending on your setup.

Therefore, explaining the experimental setup under which the triplets `(x, y, mass)` can be determined might help to shed some light on this.

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. What kind of input can I give to help?

Comment: @Xyxyl: I revised my answer, please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @mvw The description is totally generic and encompasses "machine learning" regression methods. Of course you should always start with a very simple model (e.g. linear regression).

Comment: @ziggystar I reread the question and comments again and came to the conclusion that the poster is too secretive about his "mass", if he gives no more insight in his data he deserves not more.